# Extract specific value from a table using Beautiful Soup (Python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I looked around on Stackoverflow, and most guides seem to be very specific on extracting all data from a table. However, I only need to extract one, and just can't seem to extract that specific value from the table.

Scrape link:

https://gis.vgsi.com/portsmouthnh/Parcel.aspx?pid=38919

I am looking to extract the "Style" value from the table within the link.

Code:

```
import bs4

styleData=[]

pagedata = requests.get("https://gis.vgsi.com/portsmouthnh/Parcel.aspx?pid=38919") 
cleanpagedata = bs4.BeautifulSoup(pagedata.text, 'html.parser') 

table=cleanbyAddPD.find('div',{'id':'MainContent_ctl01_panView'})
style=table.findall('tr')[3]
style=style.findall('td')[1].text
print(style)
styleData.append(style)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you misused `find_all` function, try this solution:

```
style=table.find_all('tr')[3]
style=style.find_all('td')[1].text
print(style)
```

It will give you the expected output

Answer (score 1):

Could also do something like:

```py
import bs4 
import requests
style_data = []
url = "https://gis.vgsi.com/portsmouthnh/Parcel.aspx?pid=38919"

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
# select the first `td` tag whose text contains the substring `Style:`.
row = soup.select_one('td:-soup-contains("Style:")')
if row:
    # if that row was found get its sibling which should be that vlue you want
    home_style_tag = row.next_sibling
    style_data.append(home_style_tag.text)
```

A couple of notes

- This uses CSS selectors rather than the find methods. See [SoupSieve docs](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/combinators/) for more details.
- The `select_one` relies on the fact that the table is always ordered in a certain way, if this is not the case use `select` and iterate through the results to find the `bs4.Tag` whose text is exactly `'Style:'` then grab its next sibling

Using `select`:

```py
rows = soup.select('td:-soup-contains("Style:")')
row = [r for r in rows if r.text == 'Style:']
home_style_text = row.text
```

Comment: So I tried this out, but kept getting the error code "NotImplementedError"

    table=cleanbyAddPD.find('div',{'id':'MainContent_ctl01_panView'})
    style = cleanbyAddPD.select_one('td:-soup-contains("Style:")')
    style=style.next_sibling
    print(style)
    styleData.append(style)

Comment: Not sure how to put this into easily viewable code block

Comment: Please include the full error text. My guess is that your version doesn't have the `-soup-contains` pseudo-class, the docs mention it is relatively new. The old version is `:contains`. Here are the [SoupSieve docs](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/pseudo-classes/#:-soup-contains) on that

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS Selector:

`#MainContent_ctl01_grdCns tr:nth-of-type(4)  td:nth-of-type(2)`

Which will select the `"MainContent_ctl01_grdCns"` `id`, the fourth `<tr>`, the second `<td>`.

To use a CSS Selector, use the [`.select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method instead of `find_all()`. Or `select_one()` instead of `find()`.

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://gis.vgsi.com/portsmouthnh/Parcel.aspx?pid=38919"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")
print(
    soup.select_one(
        "#MainContent_ctl01_grdCns tr:nth-of-type(4)  td:nth-of-type(2)"
    ).text
)
```

Output:

```
Townhouse End
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:contains` on a `td` to get the node with `innerText` "Style" then an adjacent sibling combinator with `td` type selector to get the adjacent `td` value.

```
import bs4, requests

pagedata = requests.get("https://gis.vgsi.com/portsmouthnh/Parcel.aspx?pid=38919") 
cleanpagedata = bs4.BeautifulSoup(pagedata.text, 'html.parser') 
print(cleanpagedata.select_one('td:contains("Style") + td').text)
```